# "status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException","message":"REJECTED_THREAD_EXECUTION"}

Tags: spring-boot, jmeter, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix

{"timestamp":1531026130373,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException","message":"REJECTED_THREAD_EXECUTION"}

I am getting above exception while running stress testing on my one of the API redirecting from zull gateway.

Here is some of the more points which I want to mentioned here.

1. I am using netflix zull and eureka for discovery my microservices (spring boot).
2. Everything is working fine from my angular application, postman and swagger.
3. Now I am trying to do stress testing using Jmeter tool which is working fine for 10 users load. But as soon as I am mentioning more than 10 no. of thread users. It is giving me above mentioned exception.
4. I tried to replicate same scenario on my local laptop and used the same jmeter. And this time rather giving the server host name I try to test with my laptop hostname (all code and services are same). I mentioned 10+ no. of thread users in jmeter and that is working fine with no above exception.

I read lot of stack-overflow posts, github links and other web search for this issue but none of solution seems to working. I tried and some other

ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 60000
  ConnectTimeout: 60000

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue of tested application :

You reported a bug without enough information here:

- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3064